# Jquery append/html div not functioning, wrong css?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have html code snippet below,
It will not display anything in the div "itemContent"
unless I type it in. I can debug and I can tell that the appropriate data
is getting passed to the "sucessfil", however nothing shows up on the div it appends!
Is there anything wrong with my CSS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sucessfil(data) 
{
$('#itemContent').append(data);

}
function displayItem(param)
    {
         $.ajax({
         url: 'ItemViewer.php?id='+param, 
         success:sucessfil
    });
    } 

function showItemInViewer(param) 
{
    el = document.getElementById("ItemViewer");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    if(param!='')
    {
        displayItem(param);

    }

 }
 </script>
 <style>
 #itemViewer
{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;

    background-color:#666
}
 #itemViewer div
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-color:#F30
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<a href='#' onClick="showItemInViewer('57');" >thrilled</a>
<div id="MoodViewer">
<div id="moodContent">
   <img href='#' 
    onclick="showItemInViewer('');" src="images/Exit.png" align="right"></img>

</div>
```

Comment: `</style>` tag is not closed. also there is no  `displayMood` function

Comment: div or element ItemViewer is missing in html.

Comment: @umar , just a suggestion , instead of document.get , use jquery $('#id') which will much cleaner

Comment: diEcho if you look at my posts you will see i answer my own question usually

Comment: I didn't say anything about "itemData" ??

Comment: as for the corrections, thank you. i changed the names around from the original which said "mood" instead of "item" but i guess it wasn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It takes the href attribute from a link class type item and send it to ItemViewer.

```
$('a.item').live('click',function(event) {
       $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ItemViewer.php',
          data:'id=' + $(this).attr('href');
          sucess: function(data) {
                  $('#ItemContent').append(data);
          }
       });
       event.preventDefault();
 }
```

HTML, example:

```
<a class="item" href="57">Item X</a>
<a class="item" href="45">Item Y</a>
<div id="ItemContent"></div>
```

Comment: @user , instead of append you can use .html, and it will wrap the results inside item content...

Comment: @kobe, I want to use append because i have a close button in my div

Comment: @user, the browser puts the number in the address bar. i suppose event.preventDefault() was supposed to stop that?

Comment: That's right. Each time you use links or submit buttons, you should add event.preventDefault() to avoid normal behavior.